# What does this notation "a" here mean in the sum in contraction?

Tags: notation, tensors

> [image]

What does "a" at the last position mean? Can I get a concrete example? Here the notation means

$$T_{i_1,\dots, i_k}{}^{j_1\dots j_\ell} = T(\partial_{i_1},\dots,\partial_{i_k},dx^{j_1},\dots, dx^{j_\ell})$$

From what I understand the contraction is some sort of inner product, but the context is not entirely clear to me.

Comment: $a$ is the index of the sum

Comment: @MarkS., okay but what would say an element $T_{i_1, I_2a}^{j_1,j_2a}$ mean for say $a= 2$?

Comment: You have the definition of the Tensor notation in your post, so set $k$ and $\ell$ to 3 and $i_3$ and $j_3$ to 2.

Comment: @MarkS. That's what I am saying, $T_{i_1, I_2a}^{j_1,j_2a}$ the quantity doesn't make sense to me, what would the "a" in the last index there mean? A placeholder? Where does the "a" go inside the arguments of $T$?

Answer (score 1):

Here $a$ is literally just playing the role of $i_k$ and $j_\ell$.  In other words, $$T_{i_1\dots i_{k-1} a}{}^{j_1\dots j_{\ell-1} a} = T(\partial_{i_1},\dots,\partial_{i_{k-1}},\partial_a,dx^{j_1},\dots, dx^{j_{\ell-1}},dx^a).$$  Note that $\partial_a$ and $dx^a$ make sense because $a$ ranges from $1$ to $n$.

Comment: Yeah it took me a while to see such through the simple notation. For the contraction here, How is the $dx^a$ done? I know for $\partial_k$, we just take the inner product with $\partial_k$ to eliminate the last one. Do we just take $dx^k(\partial_k)$ for the evaluation?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to say.